# Python - Adding class instance name to a list

Tags: python

Each time I instantiate an object of the class, I want to add the instance to a list

```
example_obj_list = []

class RandomObject:
    def __init__(self, some_property):
        self.some_property = some_property

x = RandomObject('purple')
y = RandomObject('blue')
z = RandomObject('brown')
```

How do I add a step to `__init__` so that it automatically appends each object to the list?

Comment: `property` is a builtin name and it might not be a great idea to mask it.

Comment: You named your list as `obj`, but your text says you want only names.  Which is correct?  I wrote an answer to cover the more general case.

Comment: @gahooa I fixed that, thank you.

Comment: @Prune I did want the objects rather than the names, I initially wanted names just to keep track of how many were made. Your answer also let me access object data. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to do this within the class, then the list should be a class object:

```
class RandomObject:

    example_obj_list = []

    def __init__(self, some_property):

        self.property = some_property

        # This is accessing the class attribute (not instance attribute)
        self.example_obj_list.append(self)

x = RandomObject('purple')
y = RandomObject('blue')
z = RandomObject('brown')

# Because this was defined at the class level, it can be accessed via the class itself.
for obj in RandomObject.example_obj_list:
    print(obj.property)
```

Output:

```
purple
blue
brown
```